# Switching the order of integration for a general, infinite region?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

This is probably a stupid question, but if you had a non-rectangular, infinite region R, e.g.
$$a \leq x \leq \infty$$
$$f(x) \leq y \leq g(x)$$

is it even possible to switch the order of integration when evaluating the double integral:
$$\iint_{R} f(x,y) dA$$

I don't think it is, but I wanted a second opinion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \geq 0$ we can take the order of integration any way we please, so that $\iint_R f(x,y) dA = \int dx \int dy 1_R(x,y) f(x,y) = \int dy \int dx 1_R(x,y) f(x,y)$, where $1_R$ is the indicator function on $R$, that is $1$ if $(x,y) \in R$ and $0$ otherwise.

If $\iint_R |f(x,y)|dA < \infty$, then you can also apply the above formula.

These are results of the [Fubini-Tonelli Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm aware of those theorems, but surely there isn't a second iterated integral? In this scenario, you would have to use dA = dy dx, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a second iterated integral". And there is a bit of a technical distinction between $dA$ and $dx\ dy$, but this is more of an issue in pure/math analysis. You should think of $dA$ as integrating w/r/t "area" while $dx\ dy$ and $dy\ dx$ as doing iterated integrals.

Comment: I think I realized, what you meant about second iterated integral. You are right. Making edit now.

Comment: Ok cool cheers. Was a slightly stupid question from me, but thanks for taking the time to answer.